# Can't stop animation on last frame

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I'm trying to play a character jumping animation which I want to stop on last frame, but it does not stop. I tried using

> animation-fill-mode: forwards;

with no result.

Below is the code I'm using

```
.kia-jump {
    width: 320px;
    height: 464px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 41%;
    background: url('../images/activity/KiaJumpingAnimation.png') left center;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation: jumpAnim 1.67s steps(24) 1;
}

@keyframes jumpAnim {
    100% { background-position: -7920px; }
}
```

Here's the link to the JSFiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/k4rz5tdy/

Comment: Just put all on animation: jumpAnim 1.67s steps(24) 1 forwards

Comment: @PaoloCargnin: I think you are correct. Animation is a shorthand and so there is every chance of the previous setting getting overridden.

Comment: @PaoloCargnin Didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have one extra *step* and as your `background` is set as `repeat` by default, it just go back to the first frame at the end.

```
.kia-jump {
    width: 320px;
    height: 464px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 41%;
    background: url('http://schoolcinema-sconline.rhcloud.com/images/activity/KiaJumpingAnimation.png') left center;
    animation: jumpAnim 1.67s steps(23) 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes jumpAnim {
    100% { background-position: -7590px; }
}
```

Just did

> 7920 - (7920/24) = 7590

https://jsfiddle.net/RedBreast/k4rz5tdy/2/

Comment: That worked like a charm.. You are a rockstar ;) Thanks for the help.. I was tired running behind "forwards" :)